# Using array to populate textfields

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I have this textFields

name, description.

And i have this array.

```
{"id":3157,"name":"Zhonya's Hourglass","gold":{"base":500,"total":3260,"sell":2282,"purchasable":true},"description":"<stats>+120 Ability Power<br>+50 Armor  </stats><br><br><active>UNIQUE Active - Stasis:</active> Champion becomes invulnerable and untargetable for 2.5 seconds, but is unable to move, attack, cast spells, or use items during this time (90 second cooldown).","sanitizedDescription":"+120 Ability Power +50 Armor UNIQUE Active - Stasis: Champion becomes invulnerable and untargetable for 2.5 seconds, but is unable to move, attack, cast spells, or use items during this time (90 second cooldown).","colloq":"zhg;zonyas","plaintext":"Activate to become invincible but unable to take actions","depth":3,"from":["3191","1058"],"tags":["Armor","SpellDamage","Active"],"maps":{"10":false,"8":false},"image":{"full":"3157.png","sprite":"item1.png","group":"item","x":384,"y":144,"w":48,"h":48},"stats":{"FlatArmorMod":50.0,"FlatMagicDamageMod":120.0}}
```

How can i populate each field with name: and description: without using array[index]?

I tried using dataProvider but i don't know how to refer to name or description

Comment: That would be a JSON object, not an ARRAY.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is just an object (or if it's a string loaded from an external source it's JSON), you can access the properties the same way you access any object:

```
var data:Object = JSON.decode(YOUR_JSON_STRING); //use this line if it's a string
var data:Object = {"id":3157,"name":"Zhonya's Hourglass","gold":{"base":500,"total":3260,"sell":2282,"purchasable":true},"description":"<stats>+120 Ability Power<br>+50 Armor  </stats><br><br><active>UNIQUE Active - Stasis:</active> Champion becomes invulnerable and untargetable for 2.5 seconds, but is unable to move, attack, cast spells, or use items during this time (90 second cooldown).","sanitizedDescription":"+120 Ability Power +50 Armor UNIQUE Active - Stasis: Champion becomes invulnerable and untargetable for 2.5 seconds, but is unable to move, attack, cast spells, or use items during this time (90 second cooldown).","colloq":"zhg;zonyas","plaintext":"Activate to become invincible but unable to take actions","depth":3,"from":["3191","1058"],"tags":["Armor","SpellDamage","Active"],"maps":{"10":false,"8":false},"image":{"full":"3157.png","sprite":"item1.png","group":"item","x":384,"y":144,"w":48,"h":48},"stats":{"FlatArmorMod":50.0,"FlatMagicDamageMod":120.0}};

nameTextField.text = data.name;
descriptionTextField.text = data.description
```

You probably don't want to call your name textfield `name`, as it may conflict with the existing name property on most displayObjects.